# How to encrypt repository secret for Github Action Secrets API

Tags: go, github-actions, github-api

To use the Github Action Secrets API for creating repository secret, we have to encrypt the secret key using sodium library. Github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-a-repository-secret). Example for Go is not provided. Could anybody help me out by writing a function to encrypt the secret?

My current implementation is as follows:

```golang
func EncodeWithPublicKey(text string, publicKey string) (string, error) {
    // Decode the public key from base64
    publicKeyBytes, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(publicKey)
    fmt.Printf("%x\n\n", publicKeyBytes)

    // Generate a key pair
    _, privateKey, _ := box.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
    fmt.Printf("Private key: %x\n\n", *privateKey)

    // Convert publickey to bytes
    var publicKeyDecoded [32]byte
    copy(publicKeyDecoded[:], publicKeyBytes)

    // Encrypt the secret value
    nonce := new([24]byte)
    encrypted := box.Seal(nil, []byte(text), nonce, &publicKeyDecoded, privateKey)
    fmt.Printf("%x\n\n", encrypted)

    // Encode the encrypted value in base64
    encryptedBase64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(encrypted)
    fmt.Printf("%x\n\n\n", encryptedBase64)

    return encryptedBase64, nil
}
```

I am using `golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box`.

The action secret is set incorrectly as of current implementation because the build process prompts me with an error "apiToken not found". However, if I set the secret using GitHub's website, the deployment works.

Comment: None of the examples in the GitHub docs authenticate the cipher text. Have you tried using SealAnonymous instead of Seal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change `Seal` to `SealAnonymous`

```golang
func EncodeWithPublicKey(text string, publicKey string) (string, error) {
    // Decode the public key from base64
    publicKeyBytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(publicKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Decode the public key
    var publicKeyDecoded [32]byte
    copy(publicKeyDecoded[:], publicKeyBytes)

    // Encrypt the secret value
    encrypted, err := box.SealAnonymous(nil, []byte(text), (*[32]byte)(publicKeyBytes), rand.Reader)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    // Encode the encrypted value in base64
    encryptedBase64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(encrypted)

    return encryptedBase64, nil
}
```

Comment: After finally making it work, here are a couple of things: 1) you can use `publicKeyDecoded` directly. 2) Get the right public key. If creating an environment secret, use the environment public key. There is also one for repo and one for organization.